# Tuples and ostreams: when the code breaks

Tags: c++11, tuples, iostream, c++17, variadic

When working with tuples and trying to print their values to the console using ostream you can not directly use a loop to do so since you can only access the elements of the tuple from std::get which expects a compile time constant as its template argument. So we have to use some template magic and recursion to do this for us; fair enough. I have working code that you can see below that will print a tuple through the ostream as long as all of its types are basic types:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<std::size_t> struct int_ {};

template<class Tuple, size_t Pos>
std::ostream& print_tuple( std::ostream& out, const Tuple& t, int_<Pos> ) {
    out << std::get<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - Pos>( t ) << ' ';
    return print_tuple( out, t, int_<Pos - 1>() );
}

template<class Tuple>
std::ostream& print_tuple( std::ostream& out, const Tuple& t, int_<1> ) {
    return out << std::get<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>( t );
}

template<class... Args>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const std::tuple<Args...>& t ) {
    return print_tuple( out, t, int_<sizeof...(Args)>() );
}

int main() {
    std::tuple<int, double, std::string> sample = std::make_tuple( 3, 1.723, "Hi!" );
    std::cout << sample << '\n';

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

*`Output`*

```
 3 1.723 Hi!

 Press any key to quit.
```

This seems simple enough; but wait: what if one of the tuples elements is NOT a basic type? What if one of the elements happens to be a container such as a vector, list, set or map? This above code breaks down and fails. Let's use the same code above with a another test sample of a tuple:

```
int main() {
    // This next line is perfectly fine and compiles without problems
    std::tuple<int, double, std::vector<int>> sample2 = 
      ( 1, 2.0, std::vector<int>{ 3,4,5 } ); 

    // Let's use our overloaded operator from before:
    std::cout << sample2 << '\n';
    // Oh no; the code doesn't even compile any more!

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see from the above sample the overloaded operator for the tuple is fine for all `<Args...>` that are basic types; but the code breaks as soon as one of those is a container or some other custom type.

How would one resolve this? I'm not necessarily looking for a one case fits all.
The specific case I need in my tuple is a `std::vector<int>` as shown above. If one could show me how to get the overloaded `operator<<()` for tuple working with a `std::vector<int>` I'm sure I can generalize it to work for any `std::vector<T>` as long as `<T>` is a basic type.

Comment: Can't you just overload the << operator for a vector?

Comment: @infinitezero probably yes; I'll have to give it a go.

Comment: @infinitezero wow; thank you for the advice; sometimes it's the simple things you forget about.

Comment: Few notes: 1) you can actually, up to some extent, create a tuple iterator; at least I managed once to iterate through a heterogeneous tuple with a range for-loop that printed its elements; 2) in modern C++, you can create a SFINAE-universal function that outputs a value to a stream when it is outputtable (i.e. is a RHS operand to `operator<<`) and prints some default text if not.

Comment: What surprises me is that they have not incorporated universal iostream overloads for the containers in the standard.